# Defining Custom RSpec Matchers

Tags: testing, rspec

I'm trying to create a matched for a hash defined in user_record. I tried creating a matcher.matches() as I did in be_a_boolean, but it only ever returns an object. be_a_boolean isn't a defined object, so it currently does not work.

```
  def user_record
    {
      email_address: email_address_value,
      date_of_birth: date_value,
      active:        boolean_value
    }
  end    

  def users(count)
    Array.new(count) { user_record }
  end
end    

RSpec.describe DataGenerator do     

  def match_the_shape_of_a_user_record
    # Use `be_a_boolean`, `be_a_date_before_2000` and `be_an_email_address`
    # in the hash passed to `match` below to define this matcher.    

    match(a_hash_including(
                 an_object_having_attributes(:active => be_a_boolean_value), 
                 # :date_of_birth => be_a_date_before_2000, 
                  #:email_address => be_an_email_address 
        ))
  end     

  it "generates user records" do 
    user = DataGenerator.new.user_record
    expect(user).to match_the_shape_of_a_user_record
  end     

  def all_match_the_shape_of_a_user_record
    # Combine the `all` matcher and `match_the_shape_of_a_user_record` here.    

  end    

  it "generates a list of user records" do 
    users = DataGenerator.new.users(4)
    expect(users.to all_match_the_shape_of_a_user_record)
  end 
end
```

Comment: Where's the code that define the custom matcher? https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-4/docs/custom-matchers/define-matcher

Comment: Unfortunatley, that is all it gives us. We had to create a matcher for "be_a_boolean" where I just make sure the account is true or false. The other two fields are "be_before_2000" where I just checked when the DOB is and then regex for email. When i true to have it match "be_a_boolean" it says unknown method for object